# How can i vary a parameter in function of another parameter in Anylogic?

Tags: function, parameters, simulation, anylogic

I want to add a parameter(or a variable) that I would like to vary with a slider before running the simulation. This parameter represents the money spent to launch the ad campaign. This parameter, varying must vary the parameter AdEffectiveness and in consequence the output( shown in the main plot).

#### Main

[image: Main]

#### Customer

[image: Customer]

#### AdEffectiveness

[image: AdEffectiveness]

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the link to the AnyLogic tutorial to set up parameters in the experiment page, which seems to be what you want:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd8QMBL-ri4

Answer (score 1):

Drag a slider object mySlider into your simulation experiment. In the simulation experiment's properties screen, add `mySlider.getIntValue()` in the AdEffectiveness parameter field.

More generally, if the parameter is an integer then use `mySlider.getIntValue()`, if the parameter is a double, use `mySlider.getValue()`.

In the slider properties you can set minimal and maximum values for the slider.

Comment: mySlider.getValue() should be used probably here since it returns a double.. and adEffectiveness is probably a double